# Haskell Custom Math Types and Classes

Tags: class, math, haskell, types, operator-overloading

Is there any way to make a class instance return a value which is not of the instance's type?  An example is wanting to return a value of type Double for the the scalar product of two vectors:

```
--  data structure to contain a 3D point in space
data Point3D = Point3D !Double !Double !Double
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance Num Point3D where
    -- Multiplication, scalar == Dot product
    Point3D x1 y1 z1 * Point3D x2 y2 z2 = x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2 :: Double
```

Furthermore, is there any way to define how operators work between functions of different types?  For example, I would like to define `Point3D x y z + Double a = Point3D (x + a) (y + a) (z + a)`

Comment: The main endeavour to overcome the problems of the `Num` class is the [Numeric Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Prelude).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numeric operations in the [`Num`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Num) typeclass are all defined with the type `:: Num n => n -> n -> n`, so both operands and the return value must have the same type. There's no way to alter an existing typeclass, so your options are either to define new operators or hide the existing `Num` class and replace it completely with your own implementation.

In order to implement operators that can have different operand types, you are going to need a couple of language extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
```

Instead of a `Num`-like class that encompasses `+`, `-` and `*`, it's more flexible to define different typeclasses for different operands, because while `Point3D * Double` makes sense, `Point3D + Double` usually does not. Let's start with `Mul`.

```
class Mul a b c | a b -> c where
    (|*|) :: a -> b -> c
```

Without extensions, typeclasses only ever contain a single type parameter, but with `MultiParamTypeClasses`, we can declare a typeclass like `Mul` for the combination of types `a`, `b` and `c`. The part after the parameters, `| a b -> c` is a "functional dependecy" which in this case states that the type `c` is dependent on `a` and `b`. This means that if we have an instance like `Mul Double Point3D Point3D` the functional dependency states that we can't have any other instances `Mul Double Point3D c`, where `c` something other than `Point3D`, i.e. the return type of the multiplication is always unambiguously determined by the type of the operands.

Here's how we implement instances for `Mul`:

```
instance Mul Double Double Double where
    (|*|) = (*)

instance Mul Point3D Double Point3D where
    Point3D x y z |*| a = Point3D (x*a) (y*a) (z*a)

instance Mul Double Point3D Point3D where
    a |*| Point3D x y z = Point3D (x*a) (y*a) (z*a)
```

This flexibility does not come without its caveats, though, because it will make type inference a lot more difficult for the compiler. For example, you can't simply write

```
p = Point3D 1 2 3 |*| 5
```

Because the literal `5` isn't necessarily of type `Double`. It can be any `Num n => n`, and it's entirely possible that someone declares new instances like `Mul Point3D Int Int` which behaves completely differently. So what this means is that we need to specify the types of numerical literals explicitly.

```
p = Point3D 1 2 3 |*| (5 :: Double)
```

Now, if instead of defining new operands we wish to override the default `Num` class from `Prelude`, we can do it like this

```
import Prelude hiding (Num(..))
import qualified Prelude as P

class Mul a b c | a b -> c where
    (*) :: a -> b -> c

instance Mul Double Double Double where
    (*) = (P.*)

instance Mul Point3D Double Point3D where
    Point3D x y z * a = Point3D (x*a) (y*a) (z*a)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get the standard `Num` functions (including the operators) to return a different type. `*` has the type `Num n => n -> n -> n` which means the `n` has to be the same type throughout.

There is also no way to have a standard `Num` function (like `+`) work with arguments of two different types.

The usual solution to this problem is to create a new operator. So you could create a scalar addition operator like `|+|` and use that to add doubles to your points.

If you aren't against unicode, you could use · for your dot product :). Haskell supports this, but other programs may have difficulty typing unicode.

Comment: Ah, yes, I created a custom class, but I did not think of doing a -> Double -> a.

Comment: I think this fixes both situations, it just requires that I come up with a different operator for every single different situation I have.  Very annoying.

Comment: Why could Haskell not simply have conditional operators?  If Double Point3D, then do this.  If Point3D Point3D, then do this.

Comment: Not so fast.  Take a look, for example, at the hmatrix package.  Namely, look at the <> operator, which is the matrix multiplication operator.  You can see the documentation here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.13.1.0/doc/html/Numeric-Container.html.  You can see the code at the bottom here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.13.1.0/doc/html/src/Numeric-Container.html#%3C%3E  .  He has jerry-rigged it such that <> works: Matrix <> Matrix, Vector <> Matrix, and Matrix <> Vector.  He must have abstracted away in some way that makes this look possible.

Comment: Hmm, yes he did. However, he used some extensions I am not familiar with, so I can't help you much here. Also, you'd still have to define your own operator (as opposed to using `+` or `*`).

Answer (score 4):

You can create your custom class with a multiplication that can take different types.

```
import Prelude hiding ((*))
import qualified Prelude

class Mul a b c | a b -> c where (*) :: a -> b -> c
instance Mul Double Double Double where (*) = (Prelude.*)
instance Mul Double Int Double where a * b = a Prelude.* fromIntegral b
...
```

You need to turn on multi-parameter type classes and functional dependencies for this to work.